# how to make scipy.optimize.linprog faster with different bounds for different variables?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

I am trying to use pythons scipy.optimize.linprog to optimize my model. I have about 10k variables(x's). I tried two different methods of setting the bounds for these x's.

Method 1: I have same bound for all the x's. Using this the solver seem to be running relatively fast.

Method 2: I am setting different bounds for different x's, but most of them are (0,0). This is taking much longer, around 30-45 minutes to solve this.

I am wondering if I there is any way I can make it run faster.

Also if I have the bounds for a variable xi as (0,0) but have a non-zero value for its corresponding value in A, is that ok, or do I need to set the corresponding A value to 0 too?

Comment: I highly recommend using a different solver like CBC or co. One lib supporting this would be pulp. As your two methods are different optimization-problems, there is no valid comparison and there is no real help possible. we don't know what you are doing. I also don't understand the last part.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will try the pulp. In the last part, I wanted to know if the bounds for variable x1 is (0,0) but the the value of x1 in A matrix is non-zero, would it make a difference. Should I make the corresponding x1 value 0?

Comment: That sounds you are lacking some basics. Variable-bounds are effects on variables, entries in A are constraints. Your question does not make much sense. Different entries in A describe different constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using Pulp. It is relatively faster(x3) than scipy.optimize.linprog.